# How to find out the current setting for FcgidMaxProcesses on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid

While asking this question, I feel that it may be dumb - but I have no idea at the moment...

How to find out the current setting for FcgidMaxProcesses on Apache?

**Background**

I experienced the following error: mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for ...

My Apache2 allows MaxClients=500 and the default configuration for FcgidMaxProcesses is 1000, according to [mod_fcgid docs](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxprocesses). Therefore, the MaxProcesses should not be the limiting factor - but before starting to play around with the settings, I would prefer to check the current value. So ... how do I?

Thank you

**Settings**

```
# apache2.conf
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             2
    ServerLimit             32
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        100
    ThreadLimit             64
    ThreadsPerChild         50
    MaxClients            1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>

# VirtualHost configuration
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-starter .php
    # Allow request up to 33 MB
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 34603008
    FcgidIOTimeout 300
    FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
</IfModule>

#/var/www/php-fcgi-starter
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC="/etc/php5/cgi"
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the purpose of [mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html). On the server-info page, you will see all the possible configuration options and if they are customized. If there is no custom setting, then it is the compile-time default, which does seem to be 1000 as confirmed by the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxprocesses) and [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/mod_fcgid/trunk/modules/fcgid/fcgid_conf.c?view=markup) (line 48).

Note: don't use the Location `/server-info` or create a link to your mod_info Location or you'll end up in Google like this server: http://dice.csail.mit.edu/server-info#mod_fcgid.c

Comment: mod_info is a good hint, thanks! But, as I set no configuration for the setting, this module won't tell me anything new. Is there any way to confirm the compile-time default?

Comment: I added a link to source code to confirm the default. You're most likely not compiling from source - but each distribution/packager usually has source packages you extract and check if you want to be triple sure it wasn't modified during packaging. Include distribution and package version information if you want a more detailed link.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the additional tips - I think double sure is enough :)